# Modifying existing variables inside a for loop

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scope

For my player movement, I am assigning the relevant keycodes that the user has bound via my `SettingsMaster` script to local `KeyCode` variables in my `PlayerMovement` script which is attached to my player object (eg: the forward key, 'W', is loaded into `PlayerMovement` when the user starts a level).

I want to do this in the best way possible, but unfortunately I cannot use a for loop due to variable scope. Therefore, it seems the only way to do so is by just repeating the same line of code over and over again.

```
    // What I'd like to do 
    string[] arr = { "forward", "backward", "left", "right", "crouch", "slide", "jump", "grapple", "ultimate", "primaryFire", "secondaryFire", "reload", "pause" };
    KeyCode[] keys = { forward, backward, left, right, crouch, slide, jump, grapple, ultimate, primaryFire, secondaryFire, reload, pause }; // An array of the keycode variables declared above
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        keys[i] = (KeyCode)Enum.Parse(typeof(KeyCode), SettingsMaster.GetValue(arr[i])); // Doesn't work due to variable scope

    // What I'm stuck with right now
    forward = (KeyCode)Enum.Parse(typeof(KeyCode), SettingsMaster.GetValue("forward"));
    backward = (KeyCode)Enum.Parse(typeof(KeyCode), SettingsMaster.GetValue("backward"));
    left = (KeyCode)Enum.Parse(typeof(KeyCode), SettingsMaster.GetValue("left"));
    right = (KeyCode)Enum.Parse(typeof(KeyCode), SettingsMaster.GetValue("right"));
    crouch = (KeyCode)Enum.Parse(typeof(KeyCode), SettingsMaster.GetValue("crouch"));
    slide = (KeyCode)Enum.Parse(typeof(KeyCode), SettingsMaster.GetValue("slide"));
    jump = (KeyCode)Enum.Parse(typeof(KeyCode), SettingsMaster.GetValue("jump"));
    grapple = (KeyCode)Enum.Parse(typeof(KeyCode), SettingsMaster.GetValue("grapple"));
    ultimate = (KeyCode)Enum.Parse(typeof(KeyCode), SettingsMaster.GetValue("ultimate"));
    primaryFire = (KeyCode)Enum.Parse(typeof(KeyCode), SettingsMaster.GetValue("primaryFire"));
    secondaryFire = (KeyCode)Enum.Parse(typeof(KeyCode), SettingsMaster.GetValue("secondaryFire"));
    reload = (KeyCode)Enum.Parse(typeof(KeyCode), SettingsMaster.GetValue("reload"));
    pause = (KeyCode)Enum.Parse(typeof(KeyCode), SettingsMaster.GetValue("pause"));
```

It does seem possible to accomplish the former method via unsafe code, but this isn't recommended. So my question is, is my current solution the best way to do what I want? Or am I missing something obvious?

Edit: Pastebin for clarification https://pastebin.com/LRaciVjT

---

Notes:

- `SettingsMaster.GetValue` returns the keycode in string form as it is stored in a `PlayerPref`.
- The keycodes in `PlayerMovement` have the same name as the keys for the aforementioned PlayerPrefs.

Comment: what exactly is `KeyCode`? Are those values all possible ones within the enum?

Comment: @HimBromBeere I was just referring to there `KeyCode` variables in the `PlayerMovement`script. For example I have forward, backward and left `KeyCode` variables which I assign the relevant `KeyCode` to (eg: 'W'). Hope that makes sense.

Comment: "// Doesn't work due to variable scope" what does that mean? Which error exactly do you get? I can´t see which variable should be in-accessabible here.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I'll update my original post to make it clearer what I mean.

Comment: you still do not mention which variable you refer to with "due to variable scope". Except the `SettingsMaster` I don´t see anything unknown here.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I am trying to give values to the `KeyCode` class variables (see the pastebin) in the best way possible. My original idea was add these variables to an array and iterate through it in order to assign the relevant values. However, the class variables are not assigned values given to them in the `for` loop. Therefore, the only solution I found was to assign each class variables value interdependently (see 'What I'm stuck with right now'). This doesn't seem like a good solution, so I was wondering if their was a better way.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of two arrays, why not just a `Dictionary` and map the strings to their `KeyCode`? Then just iterate your input-array, e.g. using Linq:

```
string[] arr = { "forward", "backward", "left", "right", "crouch", "slide", "jump", "grapple", "ultimate", "primaryFire", "secondaryFire", "reload", "pause" };
var map = arr.ToDictionary(x => x, x => (KeyCode)Enum.Parse(typeof(KeyCode), SettingsMaster.GetValue(x));
```

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand what you mean by 'iterate your input-array'. Do you mean assign the `KeyCode` values via a loop from the mapped values in the dictionary? If so, from my working this causes the same variable scope issue as before. Or do you mean use the mapped values to assign to the `KeyCode` variables, something like `forward = map["forward"];`? If so, is that the best way to solve my problem?

Comment: @Wzrd can you elabrate on your scope-issue? As I don´t see any loop, it´s hard to tell where you got the problem. Anyway the `ToDictionary` already iterares your array, I edit my post to clearify.

Comment: I am trying to assign existing variables values in the best way possible (my `KeyCodes` used for player movement). Because I cannot use a loop to assign values (see my original post '// What I'd like to do') I was wondering if just repeating the same like of code `KeyCode = (KeyCode)Enum.Parse(typeof(KeyCode), SettingsMaster.GetValue(key));` was the best way do assign values due to variable scope. Hope that makes sense.